# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, exception

`createQuery` in below mentioned code throws `could not prepare statement` exception sometimes. This is not happening consistently, it only throws this exception for 10% of times this code runs, other 90% it successfully runs the query. Any idea on why this is happening?

```
Session session = DB.getInstance().getSession(Id);
DesiredObject = (DesiredObject) session.createQuery(
                "from DesiredTable where Id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", Id).uniqueResult();
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:489)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full stack trace.

Comment: @SternK Good point, just included stacktrace.

Comment: But, it is not full.

Comment: @SternK what is not null? Id is not null in the scenarios I face this Exception, Also when I check DB for that ID, I do see a result with one record.

Comment: The stack trace is not full because I do not see any your classes, only classes from hibernate packages. Could you please also show the `DesiredTable` class.

Comment: @SternK I update the specific stack trace, seems like the root cause here is a connection issue

Comment: Yes, I think so too :)